# AEM - xtype 'tags' within Multifield

Tags: aem

i'm writing a multifield of xtype tags
it's dialog is

```
                <path
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Compare Tags"
                    name="./compareTag"
                    xtype="multifield">
                    <fieldConfig
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        xtype="tags">
                        <namespaces jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <categorynm
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                maximum="1"
                                name="properties"/>
                        </namespaces>
                    </fieldConfig>
                </path>
```

it's working fine when i open dialog for first time. however, after a page refresh, the multifield items wont have any pre-populated data.
on further inspection, i have found out that the json responsible for populating the data is

```
"compareTag": [
        "properties:orientation/landscape",
        "properties:style/monochrome",
        "properties:style/color"
    ]
```

in order to show dialog with previously selected values, it should have been

```
"compareTag": [
            [
                "properties:orientation/landscape"
            ],
            [
                "properties:style/monochrome"
            ],
            [
                "properties:style/color"
            ]
        ]
```

and it's because the xtype 'tags' itself stores it's values in a multifield. can this requirement be met using OOTB functionality only.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, xtype 'Multifield' stores all it's inputs as an array of entries in crx.

So, technically my implementation of 'tags' inside multifield won't work, because xtype 'tags' itself can store multiple entries for tags. tags themselves are stored as an array in repository.

OOTB multifield won't be able to solve this problem. I'd switched my approach to use xtype 'Multifieldpanel' for achieving the same. it would work because multifieldpanel would store data as json.

```
|- MultiField (ootb multifield )
   |-fieldConfig - xtype : multifieldpanel
      |- field A (xtype:textfield example textfield)
      |- field B (xtype:pathfield example pathfield)
      |- field C (xtype:tags example tags field)
```

you could find the multifieldpanel.js over the internet and For iterating over the fields, user JSONObject API of java.

Comment: Can you post the resultant code for that? I'm looking for the same functionality